# CoreGraphics rectangle gradient

Tags: ios, core-graphics, linear-gradients

Can anyone help me in drawing one specific gradient with CoreGraphics?
Just giving the clue would be enough.
The example code whould get my deepest respect.
I need this shape:

[image]

I  tried the following code:

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithGradientBorder
{
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef ctx= CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height, 8, rect.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    size_t num_locations = 4;
    CGFloat locations[4] = { 0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[16] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, num_locations);
    CGRect currentBounds = rect;

    CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), 0.0f);
    CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMaxY(currentBounds));
    topCenter = CGPointMake( 0.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
    midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);
    CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([self CGImage], mask);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);
    return maskedImage;
}
```

but it draws the gradient only from left side.

Comment: What code have you tried so far and what did it do wrong?

Comment: extended the question

Comment: did you try rotating the context and draw again for other sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've produced one workaround.

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextRef context = currentContext;
CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
CGFloat colStep = 255 / borderWidth / 10;
colStep = colStep / 255;
for (int i = 0; i < floor(borderWidth * 10); i++) {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:colStep*i alpha:1].CGColor);
    CGFloat delta = i / 10;
    CGRect rectToDraw = CGRectMake(delta,delta,rect.size.width - delta * 2,rect.size.height - delta * 2);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectToDraw);
}


CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
topCenter = CGPointMake( 0.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
midCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
```

These 2 variables have misleading names, they aren't really top center and mid centre, they are mid left and mid right. So when you call:

```
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);
```

You are drawing the gradient from left to right.

What you need to do it to organise your points and draw the gradient 4 times (L->R, R->L, T->B, B->T). Depending on what you want to corners to look like exactly you may need to do some masking in between each gradient drawing to prevent the gradient from drawing all the way into the corner.

Comment: isn't it gonna make undesirable artefacts in corners due to gradients overlapping? I'm trying to achieve gradients docking along the rectangle diagonals (like on picture above).

Comment: That's why I said you may need to mask. Look at setting clipping paths, use triangles from the corner points to the center.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better for the original question, but if you don't need to draw with CoreGraphics, you may want to consider image slicing with the asset catalog. You can create the gradient and corners in a graphics program and make it resizable in Xcode.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class BorderView: UIView {
    private var lineHeight: CGFloat = 80
    var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.black, UIColor.white]
    {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let line1 = _getLineLayer()
    layer.addSublayer(line1)

        let line2 = _getLineLayer()
    let t = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -rect.maxY + lineHeight)
        line2.setAffineTransform(t)
        layer.addSublayer(line2)

        let line3 = _getLineLayer()
        let t1 = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:     CGFloat(M_PI_2)).translatedBy(x: rect.midX - lineHeight/2, y: -rect.midY + lineHeight/2)
        line3.setAffineTransform(t1)
        layer.addSublayer(line3)

        let line4 = _getLineLayer()
        let t2 = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(M_PI_2)).translatedBy(x: -rect.midX + lineHeight/2, y: -rect.midY + lineHeight/2)
        line4.setAffineTransform(t2)
        layer.addSublayer(line4)


    }

    private func _getLineLayer() -> CALayer {

        let gl = CAGradientLayer()
        gl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: layer.bounds.width, height: lineHeight)
        gl.colors = colors.map({$0.cgColor})

        // Get mask layer
        let p1 = CGPoint.zero
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: layer.bounds.width, y: 0)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: layer.bounds.width - lineHeight, y: lineHeight)
        let p4 = CGPoint(x: lineHeight, y: lineHeight)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.addLine(to: p2)
        path.addLine(to: p3)
        path.addLine(to: p4)
        path.close()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = gl.frame
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        gl.mask = shapeLayer
        return gl
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let view = BorderView(frame: frame)
view.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
view.colors = [.black, .white]
```

[image: Output view]